# Does Minecraft 1.6 have higher practical system requirements than 1.5.1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Playing on my (hosted) multiplayer server, I had no issue with minecraft 1.5.1, but after upgrading to 1.6, I'm lagging horribly even when alone in the server. I did increase the memory supplied to the game in the new launcher, but it didn't help much. Have the system requirements increased? And, if so, is it the server or the client that needs more resources?

Comment: Most like it's just new performance bugs.

Comment: I believed they increased the graphical requirements for the game. I do believe they removed support of openGL 2.0 which may be due to upgrades done to performance. I don't know, it may just be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/325948-minecraft-system-requirements

Current Minecraft system requirements

> Last Updated: Sep 20, 2013 11:58AM CEST
>
> A computer with the minimum requirements should be able to play
> Minecraft. However, for the best experience, please consider the
> recommended requirements.
>
> ### Minimum Requirements:
>
> - CPU : Intel P4 or its AMD Equivalent (AMD K7)
> - RAM : 2GB
> - GPU : Intel GMA 950 or AMD Equivalent with OpenGL 2.1 Support
> - HDD : At least 100MB for Game Core and Sound Files
>
> ### Recommended Requirements:
>
> - CPU : Intel Pentium D or AMD Athlon 64 (K8) 2.6 GHz
> - RAM : 4GB
> - GPU : GeForce 6xxx or ATI Radeon 9xxx and up with OpenGL 2.1 Support (Excluding Integrated Chipsets)
> - HDD : 150MB
>
> ### Software Requirements:
>
> - Minecraft Release 1.6 or newer. Older versions will need to be updated to current versions**
> - Java (Java SE 6 Update 51 or Java SE 7 Update 40 or newer is preferred)
> - Please note that some users experience issues playing Minecraft while using a mismatched version of Java for their operating system
>   (32 or 64 bit), while using certain versions of Java 7, or while
>   multiple versions of Java are installed
>
> If you have a laptop with an a built-in (integrated) graphics card,
> rather than a dedicated card, it is highly suggested that you try the
> demo before purchase.

Information on system requirements for running a Minecraft server can be found on the Minecraft wiki.

Compare to previous:

> ### Minimum (As of 1.5.2):
>
> - CPU : Intel P4/NetBurst architecture or its AMD equivalent (AMD K7)
> - RAM : 256 MB
> - GPU : GeForce 256 or ATI Rage XL and up. (Any GPU with OpenGL 1.2 support)
> - HDD : At least 10 MB for game data
>
> ### Recommended:
>
> - CPU : Intel Pentium D or AMD K8-Based CPUs and better
> - RAM : 1 GB
> - GPU : GeForce 7300 GT or ATI Radeon HD 2400 XT and up
> - HDD : 150 MB for game saves + sounds

### Net increases:

Minimum:

- CPU : Netburst architecture / ***no increase***
- RAM : 256MB to 2GB / ***1.75GB INCREASE***
- GPU : GeForce 256 or ATI Rage XL to Intel GMA 950 or AMD Equivalent / ***no easily documented increase***
- HDD : 10MB to 100MB / ***90MB INCREASE***

Recommended:

- CPU : Intel Pentium D or AMD K8 (2.6 Ghz-ish) to Intel Pentium D or AMD Athlon 64/K8 (2.6 GHz) / ***no increase***
- RAM : 1GB to 4GB / ***3GB INCREASE***
- GPU : GeForce 7300 GT or ATI Radeon HD 2400 XT and up to GeForce 6xxx or ATI Radeon 9xxx and up with OpenGL 2.1 Support / ***OpenGL 1.2 to OpenGL 2.1***
- HDD : 150MB to 150MB / ***no increase***

Note: this is for the minecraft client. Server specs are available [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server#General_recommendations).

Answer (score -3):

Yes, they increased the graphical requirements of the game and the 1.6.2 version requires more memory to play than 1.5.1
System requirements:

### Current

- Windows XP / Vista / 7 / 8
- Mac OS X (Tested on OS X Lion/Mountain Lion, works on any version?)
- Ubuntu (Tested on 12.04, works on any version?)
- Debian Stable

Also; Java 6+

### Prior

- Windows Vista / 7 / 8
- Mac OS X
- Ubuntu, Debian Stable

Also; Java 5

The physical memory increased. From 1.5.1 to 1.6 the requirement increased about 1298.4 KB.

Comment: Needing more memory =/= increased graphical requirements. Can you provide something else to support the statement that the graphical requirements have been increased?

Comment: How much more does it need than the prior?

Comment: You've just listed a bunch of operating systems. What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: A physical memory change is sorta hard to quantify.  A single meg is negligible, anyway you look at it.  Where'd you come up with that?

Comment: I downloaded the older version and compared it with the newest one.

Comment: They also added more libraries - 18 currently in use and 3 irrelevant.